# $http multiple transformRequests overwriting each other

Tags: angularjs, http, service, request, transform

I inject the user's access token into every request using this code:

```
$injector.get('$http').defaults.transformRequest = function(data, headersGetter) {
    if ($rootScope.auth.accessToken) {
      headersGetter()['access_token'] = $rootScope.auth.accessToken;
      return angular.toJson(data);
    } else {
      return angular.toJson(data); 
    }
  };
```

One of my requests sends a file, so I have to modify the request in the *service* with `transformRequest` before (I assume) the `access_token` transform to make sure that Angular's default `transformRequest` does not serialize the `FormData`. The `Content-Type` is `undefined` so that Angular will fill in the correct boundary. More on this function can be found [here](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs).

```
this.upload = function(file) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('contacts', file);
    return $http.post(baseUrl + '/contacts/uploads', fd, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    });
  };
```

The problem is that when the request is transformed in the *service* (directly above), the `access_token` is never added by the second transform (the first code block) before the request leaves the app, meaning my requests to the API are unauthorized. I know this is the case, because if I add the `access_token` manually, it works, like so:

```
this.upload = function(file) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('contacts', file);
    return $http.post(baseUrl + '/contacts/uploads', fd, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {'access_token': $rootScope.auth.accessToken, 'Content-Type': undefined}
    });
  };
```

**How can I add the `access_token` using a transform programmatically after the first transform? Why can't the request be transformed again after the first time?**